# How to programmatically add domain for allowed cookies?

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

Under `chrome://settings/content/cookies`, I can 'Add' a domain to my organisations allowed default set. How can I do this programmatically in Java for my web tests to use?

Comment: Do you want add cookies to allow ? Can you provide more details ?

Comment: I want to allow cookies from a new domain, from the link above I can manually do this via 'Add' say allowing domain 'https://example.com' but this is only added to my user profile, a new ChromeDriver instance won't have this domain allowed by default. It needs to be set somehow.

Comment: You can try the code, I have posted and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In selenium, you can try like this.

```
WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();        
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie-name", "cookie-value");
chromeDriver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: I don't want to add a cookie, I want to allow a domain to set a cookie in Chrome, we have an organisation policy in chrome allowing known domains to set cookies only, I want to add to this domain list. I can do this manually but don't know how to do it via selenium webdriver.

Comment: Can you add domain name as cookie-value as I have provided the code and try ?

Comment: This sadly didn't work and resulted in a cookie being created unnecessarily.